# How to change radioButton text and appearance on selected

Tags: android, selector

So this is a radio group:[image]

As you can see "New York" is selected right now. So how do I make the text bigger and add a red line underneath when it is selected and have it return to normal when it isnt? I am aware that I can use a selector and have two images, but i want to be able to support multiple languages so I need to link the text to a strings.xml file(correct me if that assumption was wrong.) I also tried changing the text in the selector but apparently it doesnt support that, so How would i accomplish this? Thanks!!

Comment: i should say that this is a native android application and im using java/xml

Comment: Html is a native Android class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Answer (score 0):

Try Html.fromHtml() in your setText method like this in your event listener

```
button.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font size='@theSizeYourWant' style='border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000'><u>New York</u></font>"));
```

Comment: thanks, the underline worked however i dont think the border worked at all as its just the regular white underline u get with<u>. The font size=... also did not work, could something be wrong with your syntax? or do I have to add anything to my manifest to use html in android? Im not really familiar to html, thanks in advance!